# Use qdisc to send out packets at a pre-determined schedule

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking

I would like to queue all outgoing packets on an interface, and release them at pre-determined points in time. Programs can send packets whenever they wish, but they will all be held back before being transfered out of the system. Every 250ms (or so), the system should release all queued packets.

Can you do this with qdisc? If so how, if not, what is an alternative that could support this?

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: In essence, I'm trying to schedule packets in a deterministic pattern to hide the CPU load. Intuition (and my experimentation) clearly show that latency increases on CPU load, and I would try to see if it is possible to hide this.